# Is it possible to include templates within templates with separate contexts?

Tags: node.js, templates, handlebars.js

I'm developing an application in nodejs and handlebars.

I'd like to be able to create a layout template then add various individual components within that layout.

Each component would be created with a separate handlebars template and context.
e.g. layout.tmpl

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <!-- somehow render a handlebars template here with a separate context -->

  <!-- somehow render another handlebars template here with a separate context -->
<body>
</html>
```

Is this possible? If not, is there another templating engine that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible with Handlebars [partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html).